# How to combine the related version in group by

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select count(a),b,c
from APPLE
  join MANGO  on (APPLE.link=MANGO.link)
  join ORANGE  on (APPLE.link=ORANGE.link)
 where id='camel' 
group by b,c;
```

The column b gives values like

```
1.0
1.0,R
1.0,B
2.0
2.0,B
2.0,R
3.0,C
3.0,R
```

is there a way to modify the above query so that all 1.0 and 1.0,R and 1.0,B are merged as 1.0, and 2.0,2.0,B are merged as 2.0 and same way for 3.0 and 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  COUNT(a), REGEXP_REPLACE(b, '([0-9]*\.[0-9]*)(.*)', '\1') b, c
FROM    apple
JOIN    mango
ON      mango.link = apple.link
JOIN    orange
ON      orange.link = apple.link
WHERE   id = 'camel'
GROUP BY
        REGEXP_REPLACE(b, '([0-9]*\.[0-9]*)(.*)', '\1'), c
```

Comment: i get ora-00904:invalid identifier error for regexp_replace in the group by, its working fine in the fisrt line i.e., select

Comment: @randeepsp: which `Oracle` version do you use?

Comment: @randeepsp: ah, this syntax is only for 10g and above. Is the minor version guaranteed to be separated by a comma?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `substr` if you don't have access to `regexp_replace` (10g+). If you only have to aggregate from `1.0` to `4.0`:

```
SELECT COUNT(a), substr(b, 1, 3), c
  FROM APPLE
  JOIN MANGO ON (APPLE.link = MANGO.link)
  JOIN ORANGE ON (APPLE.link = ORANGE.link)
 WHERE id = 'camel'
 GROUP BY substr(b, 1, 3), c;
```

If you anticipate you may reach `10.0` you can use `instr` to get the number of characters:

```
SELECT COUNT(a),
       CASE
          WHEN instr(b, ',') > 0 THEN
           substr(b, 1, instr(b, ',') - 1)
          ELSE
           b
       END, c
  FROM APPLE
  JOIN MANGO ON (APPLE.link = MANGO.link)
  JOIN ORANGE ON (APPLE.link = ORANGE.link)
 WHERE id = 'camel'
 GROUP BY CASE
             WHEN instr(b, ',') > 0 THEN
              substr(b, 1, instr(b, ',') - 1)
             ELSE
              b
          END, c;
```